# error 404 Cannot find entry file

Tags: react-native

He creado un proyecto con React-Native y tengo este error:

> The development server returned response error code: 404
>
> URL:
>   http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false
>
> Body: {"message":"Cannot find entry file index.js in any of the roots:
>   [\"C:\\Users\\Practicas2_SI2\\ProyectosReact\\ScreenNav\"]","name":"NotFoundError","type":"NotFoundError","status":404,"errors":[{}]}
>   processBundleResult
>       BundleDownloader.java:225 access$100
>       BundleDownloader.java:40 onResponse
>       BundleDownloader.java:192 execute
>       RealCall.java:135 run
>       NamedRunnable.java:32 runWorker
>       ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113 run
>       ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588 run
>       Thread.java:818

No me ha dado tiempo a hacer nada , solo lo he creado y le he intentado añadir react-navigation...¿que puede estar pasando ?

Comment: El error dice que no encuentra el fichero index.js en la ruta C:\Users\Practicas2_SI2\ProyectosReact\ScreenNav\, comprueba la configuración del proyecto

Comment: Hola, acá en [github](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14246) hay un issue con respecto a este error, unas de las cosas que puedes ver en el link es que recomiendan usar la última versión de react-native, ya que de lo contrario te tocará correr algunos scripts.